# Cannot Target Physical Devices

Tags: android

I cannot select either of my devices from the ADT device manager. This is a (nearly) fresh install of the ADT direct from [Google](http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html). About a year ago I was using the Android plugin for Eclipse, but since that didn't work either I installed the ADT.

I have installed and updated everything under Tools, Android 4.2, and Extras in the Android SDK manager. I haven't installed anything else.

I have both a Nexus 7 (4.2.2) and a Samsung Fascinate (2.3.5) that I am trying to send my app to. I'm using the USB cable that shipped with my Nexus 7 to connect the devices to my computer. Both have USB Debugging checked.

I have not changed anything inside my test project, everything is as it was from just clicking next through the project builder.

I am using the default launch configuration, all the settings are default as well except for the Project. Here is the full console log from loading the ADT to after attempting to run on my device:

---

[2013-02-20 18:53:42 - test] ------------------------------

[2013-02-20 18:53:42 - test] Android Launch!

[2013-02-20 18:53:42 - test] adb is running normally.

[2013-02-20 18:53:42 - test] Performing com.example.test.MainActivity activity launch

[2013-02-20 18:53:42 - test] Failed to find an AVD compatible with target 'Android 4.2'.

[2013-02-20 18:54:42 - test] Performing com.example.test.MainActivity activity launch

[2013-02-20 18:54:45 - test] Launch canceled!

---

The 6th log entry occurs after the ADT gives me a dialog that says "No compatible targets were found. Do you wish to add a new Android Virtual Device?," to which I press no. The Android Device Chooser then appears, and there are no devices for me to pick from.

I have Googled that 5th log, but it turned up nothing that worked. They suggested that I change the minimum and target versions, or that I use a virtual device. I'd like to use my physical devices if possible. Thanks for any help.

Comment: does the adb binary recognize your device when you run `adb devices` ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you installed your OEM usb drivers? Have a look at this link:

http://developer.android.com/tools/extras/oem-usb.html

Comment: Thanks a bunch for that. My Nexus works now. I didn't see the Google drivers for some reason. I was able to install the driver for that just fine. Unfortunately it didn't work for my Fascinate. I have the latest version already installed in the USB port I "think" is where it is plugged in, but the Windows Device Manager does not recognize a device in the port (at all) until I unplug it, where Windows reports that the USB device was not recognized. Thanks though.

Comment: This worked for me , At first instance immediately after installing google driver i could see it in list , but target was still coming as unknown . I removed usb and reconnected it and then the deployment of app on my nexus was successful . Thanks for your help !!!